# lifetime mismatch ...but data from `ctx` flows into `ctx` here?

Tags: anchor, rust

I am trying to take in remaining accounts and deserializing it but i am getting this error i tried cloning it as well but it did not solve the issue.
[image]

```
if ctx.remaining_accounts.len() == 2 || ctx.remaining_accounts.len() == 5 && is_native == false {
    let mut renter_pay_ata_index = 0;
    let mut rent_manager_vault_ata = 1;
    if ctx.remaining_accounts.len() == 5{
        renter_pay_ata_index = 3;
        rent_manager_vault_ata = 4;
    }
    let renter_pay_ata_info = &ctx.remaining_accounts[renter_pay_ata_index];
    let renter_pay_ata = Account::<TokenAccount>::try_from(renter_pay_ata_info)?;
    if renter_pay_ata.mint != ctx.accounts.rent_manager.pay_mint || renter_pay_ata.owner != ctx.accounts.renter.key() {
        return Err(error!(ErrorCode::RenterATAWrong));
    }
    let rent_manager_vault_ata_info =  &ctx.remaining_accounts[rent_manager_vault_ata];
    let rent_manager_vault = Account::<TokenAccount>::try_from(rent_manager_vault_ata_info)?;
    if rent_manager_vault.mint != ctx.accounts.rent_manager.pay_mint || rent_manager_vault.owner != ctx.accounts.rent_manager.key() {
        return Err(error!(ErrorCode::RenterATAWrong));
    }
    msg!("ALL GOOD");
    main_renter_pay_ata = Some(renter_pay_ata);
    main_rent_manager_pay_ata = Some(rent_manager_vault);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely due to the way you set your CPIContext.
If it is currently in this format

```
pub fn custom_struct(
   ctx: Context<CustomStruct>,
) -> Result<()>
```

Try changing it to the format below

```
pub fn custom_struct<'info>(
   ctx: Context<'_, '_, '_, 'info, CustomStruct<'info>>,
) -> Result<()>
```